# understanding of the creating dll in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I created some simple dll in visual studio, to begin to use it I read the following article:

> To use the functionality from the class library in the console
>   application
>
> 1) After you create a new console application, an empty program is
>   created for you. The name for the source file is the same as the name
>   that you chose for the project earlier. In this example, it is named
>   MyExecRefsDll.cpp.
>
> 2) To use the math routines that were created in the dynamic link
>   library, you must reference the library. To do this, select the
>   MyExecRefsDll project in the Solution Explorer, then select
>   References… from the Project menu. On the Property Pages dialog box,
>   expand the Common Properties node, select Framework and References,
>   and then select the Add New Reference… button. For more information
>   about the References… dialog box, see Framework and References, Common
>   Properties,  Property Pages Dialog Box.
>
> 3) The Add Reference dialog box is displayed. This dialog lists all
>   the libraries that you can reference. The Project tab lists all the
>   projects in the current solution and any libraries they contain. On
>   the Projects tab, select MathFuncsDll. Then click OK.
>
> 4) To reference the header files of the dynamic link library, you must
>   modify the include directories path. To do this, on the Property Pages
>   dialog box, expand the Configuration Properties node, expand the C/C++
>   node, and then select General. Next to Additional Include Directories,
>   type the path of the location of the MathFuncsDll.h header file.
>
> 5) The executable does not load dynamic link libraries until runtime.
>   You must tell the system where to locate MathFuncsDll.dll. You do so
>   by using the PATH environment variable. To do this, on the Property
>   Pages dialog box, expand the Configuration Properties node and select
>   Debugging. Next to Environment, type the following: PATH=, where  is
>   replaced with the actual location of MathFuncsDll.dll. Click OK to
>   save all the changes.*

I understand why we need to set a location for the header and dll (paragraphs 4 and 5), my question is why we need paragraphs 2 and 3 to reference the library? thanks in advance for any simple explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 2 and 3 describe steps to help create a managed project, one that uses the .NET framework. 
It is calling referencing an assembly, and is equivalent to linking in a library file for native apps.
I take it you are creating a C++/CLI managed application?

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN [Framework and References, Common Properties,  Property Pages Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47w1hdab.aspx) "Use this property page to set references from a C++ project to .NET Framework assemblies, COM components, or external projects."
Mostly for managed C++, i guess. References are used extensively in VB.NET/C# projects.

Answer (score 0):

Steps 2/3 are needed to tell the linker where to find the compiled versions of the library so that it can link against them. You might find this useful: http://www.lurklurk.org/linkers/linkers.html